# Не получается вызвать метод GET в простом приложении на Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Пытаюсь осваивать Spring. Решил написать простой REST API запрос GET. Но при вызове  локально постоянно ловлю 404. Понять в чём проблема не могу, пожалуйста помогите новичку, ткните носом, что не так(

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>RestApiTest</groupId>
<artifactId>Rest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Класс:

```
    @SpringBootApplication

public class SpringRestLesson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringRestLesson.class);
    }

}
```

Контроллер:

```
@RestController
public class ExampleRestController {

        public static class RestResponse{

            private String param1;
            private String param2;

            public String getParam1() {
                return param1;
            }

            public void setParam1(String param1) {
                this.param1 = param1;
            }

            public String getParam2() {
                return param2;
            }

            public void setParam2(String param2) {
                this.param2 = param2;
            }

            @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public RestResponse restMethod(String name){

        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        res.setParam1("Hello");
        res.setParam2(name);

        return res;
    }
}

}
```

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: у вас контроллер без методов, вам нечем запрос ловить, вот и не ловится. Вот [краткий и понятный пример](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller#spring-mvc-rest-controller).

Comment: @tym32167 ,а как же public RestResponse restMethod(String name){...}.

Comment: Так это метод вложенного класса, а не класса контроллера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй переделать контроллер:

```
@RestController
public class ExampleRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String restMethod(String name){
       return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

И посмотри ответ. А то у тебя много лишнего в контроллере смешано.